# How to avoid the product's limit for taxonomy in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Recently I'm faced with an interesting effect which seems to go with default settings.

When you just display products in mixed order it's ok, but when you're trying to create custom category for them - there are I'm getting the limit for loop: only 12 products are displayed in tab for category's list.
E.g.:

there are 12 items of watches in "Men watches" tab:

[image: here are 12 items of watches]

but in fact, there are 16 of them:

[image]

Usually I add categories this way using standart form:

[image]

and add products to them:

[image]

In my functions.php file I added the line to extend the amount of products globally, but it didn't help:

[image]

Why the amount of rendered products by their categories is limited? Where to find the code that is in charge of this case?

Comment: Since you tagged `php`, consider adding some relevant code. BTW, is it possible that 4 of your 16 products are "hidden" or "out of stock"?

Comment: All product archives have the `posts_per_page` query argument set via [`loop_shop_per_page`](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/class-wc-query.php#L438) filter or falling back to the `posts_per_page` option in the admin settings. I can't quite tell if you are referring to shortcodes or term archives?

Comment: @helgatheviking added some information about this topic, I did it, but it doesn't help.

Comment: Still need to know *where* this problem is occurring. Archives? Shortcode? Related posts tab? Also I would advise temporarily switching to a default theme to try to determine if it is something your theme is doing. Same goes for disabling other plugins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options you could give a try:

1. If you are filtering by category, you are probably using the

`["product_category"]`

where the default per_page attribute is set to be 12. You can override that by specifying the per_page="16".

2. Try to set a priority to your add_filter function in the functions.php file, like

`add_filter("loop_shop_per page", create_function('$cols', 'return 16'), 20);`

Hope you get it to work.

Greetings

Comment: I'm glad it worked. Always read through the Documentation of a certain class, because there are some attributes that are being set with default values, and you end up with the issue you just had.

Comment: Ok, I just had no Idea what class should I read, because I'm using the theme that wasn't developed by myself.

Comment: And it's also interesting that in the end of the page there are no pagination, products are just cutted out below the 12'th element.